# How did the pensieve float in air?

Tags: harry-potter

In Harry Potter Deathly Hallows Part 2, when Harry goes to Dumbledore chamber to see about Snape's memory, he heaves the pensieve and it floated in air. How does it float without magic?
[image: Dumbledore is dead by that time.]

Harry doesn't have enough capability to do wandless Magic by that time.

[image: We can see here that the penesieve is without support.]

Comment: Erm, objects can be imbued with magic.

Comment: Why would you think that an object that shows you memories *with* magic, floats "without magic"?

Comment: I don't recall the Pensieve floating in the books, so I just chalk this up to artistic license in the movies.

Comment: Because the filmmakers were convinced two seconds without exciting-magic-whizzbang effects will bore the audience. Speaks volumes about who they thought they were targeting, really.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Pensieve does not float in the book.

> Harry glanced hopelessly at Dumbledore’s deserted frame, which hung directly behind the headmaster’s chair, then turned his back on it. The stone Pensieve lay in the cabinet where it had always been. Harry heaved it onto the desk and poured Snape’s memories into the wide basin with its runic markings around the edge. To escape into someone else’s head would be a blessed relief...Nothing that even Snape had left him could be worse than his own thoughts. The memories swirled, silver white and strange, and without hesitating, with a feeling of reckless abandonment, as though this would assuage his torturing grief, Harry dived.
>
> <sub><sup>Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Chapter 33, The Prince’s Tale</sup></sub>

I think it was added to make the moment look special because it was revealing of real Severus Snape.

Comment: It certainly fits the moment better visually rather than him "heaving" a huge stone dish about at this tense time. It's fine in the book but this works better in a visual medium I would say.

Comment: I can't agree more.